# Passing function with Subclass as argument to function which takes any function with Super class as parameter

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

I have following scala code.

```
trait Super
case class Sub(value:String) extends Super
case class YetAnotherSub(value:String) extends Super
case class OnlyErrorType(value:String) extends Super

def function1[I <: Super, R](mapper : (I) => R, input: Super) (default: R): R = input match {
  case error: OnlyErrorType => 
    default

  case success: I => mapper(success)  // Ideally success => mapper(success)

  case _ => default // I don't want this line at all, as I'm not expecting any other type
}

def function2(input:String):Super = if(input.size >= 3) Sub("Greater") else OnlyErrorType("Lesser")

def function3(input:String):String = {
  val result = function2(input)
  function1({sub:Sub => sub.value.toUpperCase}, result) ("Empty Result")
}

function3("Input")
```

There are various functions similar to `function2` which accepts some parameters and return any subtype of `Super`. I would like to have a generic mapper, like `function1`, to map type `Super` to some other type, but return a default value in case of `OnlyErrorType`

In other words I would like to have some default handling for `OnlyErrorType`, but let calling function(in this case `function3`) specify the mapping for SuccessType (any sub types of `Super` except `OnlyErrorType`).

How do I achieve this ?

Above code compiles, but I hate to see warning,

```
warning: abstract type pattern I is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

I think there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good you don't like the warning; in this case it basically means the test doesn't work.

The simplest approach is to make `SuccessType` explicit:

```
sealed trait Super
trait SuccessType extends Super
case class Sub(value:String) extends SuccessType
case class YetAnotherSub(value:String) extends SuccessType
case class OnlyErrorType(value:String) extends Super

def function1[R](mapper: SuccessType => R, input: Super) (default: R): R = input match {
  case _: OnlyErrorType => default
  case success: SuccessType => mapper(success)
}
```

Note that because `Super` is sealed, it can't be extended *directly* elsewhere, but one of its subtypes can be, so you can add new `SuccessType`s. If that's not desired, make `SuccessType` `sealed` as well.
Of course, in this case `function1({case sub:Sub => sub.value.toUpperCase}, result) ("Empty Result")` will fail if it's passed a `YetAnotherSub`. If that's not what you want, then you need to distinguish "`Super` which is `Sub` if successful" and "`Super` which is `YetAnotherSub` if successful" statically. You can use

```
sealed trait Super[I <: Super[I]]
case class Sub(value:String) extends Super[Sub]
case class YetAnotherSub(value:String) extends Super[YetAnotherSub]
case class OnlyErrorType[I <: Super[I]](value:String) extends Super[I]

def function1[I <: Super[I], R](mapper : (I) => R, input: Super[I]) (default: R): R = input match {
  case error: OnlyErrorType[_] =>
    default

  case success => mapper(success.asInstanceOf[I])
}

def function2(input:String):Super[Sub] = if(input.size >= 3) Sub("Greater") else OnlyErrorType("Lesser")

def function3(input:String):String = {
  val result = function2(input)
  function1({sub:Sub => sub.value.toUpperCase}, result) ("Empty Result")
}

function3("Input")
```

But I would prefer not to: the cast in `function1` is actually safe, but it isn't trivially so (and defining new subtypes of `Super` incorrectly can break it).

Comment: I would have loved your first suggestion if it worked. It doesn't compile.

Comment: Fixed the suggestion.